# Custom reaction emoji discord js: "Client undefined"

Tags: javascript, emoji, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a roleReact bot. The stock emojis are working and I based some on the official document of `discord.js`, but when it comes to custom emoji reactions I keep getting the result

> client undefined

This is my code so far:

```
case "react":
// this works
message.react("").then(reaction => console.log(typeof reaction));
//I keep getting a client undefiend error here
message.react( client.emojis.get("410431571083132933")).then(reaction =>  console.log(typeof reaction));
message.react("410431571083132933").then(reaction => console.log(typeof reaction));
break;
```

Does anybody know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need to provide more code. At least up to where `cilent` is defined, or in this case, not defined

Comment: @Wright I'm not trying to be rude, but you misspelled client.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure thats a valid Emoji ID?
You can't right click on a emoji and Copy ID. That would copy the ID of the message.
To get the ID of a Emoji type `\:emoji:` => `<:emoji:123123123123>`
With that ID you can react a message.

```
message.react(client.emojis.get("123123123123"))
    .then(reaction => console.log(typeof reaction));
```

Or maybe if you copy and pasted that code from somewhere, `client` is the default for the `Discord.Client()`, but some people use `bot` instead.
Give it a try with `bot` instead of `client`

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the whole getting emojis part, see if this works:

```
message.react("<:emojiNameGoesHere: 410431571083132933>").then(reaction => console.log(typeof reaction));
```

This is the text that actually is sent, and discord just erases it client side and replaces it with a emoji.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot must be on server with some custom emoji you want to use

Comment: Not necessarily, bots have an ability similar (well totally the same) as one you would get with discord nitro. They can use an emoji anywhere as long as it is part of at least one server that they (the bot) is in

Comment: I didn't mean it. The bot will not take emoji out of thin air. Therefore, he needs to take this emoji from somewhere, in our case from another server, so that he can then use it anywhere